# Why is my header implementation not working?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a feel for declaring functions in headers and implementing them on a separate file.

I have a main class from where I can instantiate World:

```
#include "World.cc"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    World say;
    say.hello();
return 0;
}
```

I keep getting an error stating:

```
"multiple definition of `World::hello()'"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include this is the `main.cpp`

`#include "HelloWorld.h"`

not the `HeloWorld.cc` file.

Comment: It'll be helpful to the OP to explain why use of `#include "HelloWorld.cc"` causes multiple definitions.

Comment: The whole point of the header file was to include it in the implementation file and all files that use it.

Comment: `HelloWorld.cc` is _already_ being compiled into your program, _along with_ `main.cc`. By `#include`ing it into `main.cc` it causes multiple instances of `World::hello()` to appear in program, which causes that error. The code in the header file is a _declaration_ only, it doesn't result in any actual compiled code, which is why it's safe to include in multiple locations.

Answer (score 2):

You want to have the *declarations* in the header file, and the *implementation* separate.  The client code (`main` in your case) only needs the declarations, so it should include the header:

```
#include "World.h"
```

Preprocessor includes are very simple; it's little more than replacing the `#include` line with the contents of the file it names.  When you included the source file `World.cc`, you caused the definitions to be built with your `main.o` object file.  Then, when you link `main.o` with `World.o`, they both contain definitions for the functions of `World.cc`.